# Headers necessary to add google analytics application in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I need help to implement GA in my first iOS application, ask me the documentation necessary to add some headers and configure monitored in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Analytics. But I understand that concerns headers. I'm programming my application on Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you add **Google Analytic** to your project in swift is as following:

1. Download the Framework from Google ([**Get Configuration file**](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=analytics&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fios%2Fv3%2Fapp%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue%23add%2Dconfig&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Analytics)) or use [CocoPods](http://CocoaPods) to install it in your pod.
2. Once you add it to your Project, make sure you create a `Bridging-Header.h` file to include the Google Analytics Modules. Following are necessary.

---

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

---

3. Open you **appDelegate.swift** file and add this to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Make sure it match your **Analytic Publisher ID/Tracking ID**

---

```
let Tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()
Tracker.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXX-X")
```

---

Now you can capture [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events) and [view](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens) by integrating them in your handlers or `viewDidAppear:` method.

#### Event Example:

```
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(
    "App",
    action: "View",
    label: "Application Launched",
    value: nil).build()

Tracker.defaultTracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

Please ask any questions you may have. :)

Comment: Thank you. It has helped me a lot.

Comment: Cool, ask me any question you have, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you integrated with Cocoapods, you should add `import Google` to the top of every file where you will write code related to Google Analytics.